# How does the return of control flow work in a chain of Express middleware functions?

Tags: express, routes, middleware

I actually have a couple of questions about Express middleware chaining and thought I'd group them in this single post since they're closely related.

---

**Q1:** In a middleware function, if I `send()` the `Response`, pass to the next function, or just return, does any of the remaining code get executed?

```
router.get('/a', (req, res, next) => {
    res.sendStatus(200);
    // Does this ever get executed?
}); 

router.get('/b', (req, res, next) => {
    next();
    // Does this ever get executed?
}); 

router.get('/c', (req, res, next) => {
    return;
    // Does this stop the middleware chain? What happens to the request/response?
});
```

---

**Q2:** Can you pass on to another middleware function from inside of the preceding one? My reason for this is that I have to supply an argument to create a certain middleware, and that argument is dependent on which Express `app` object is the owner of the `Request`. So I need to access a property of the Request before it is passed to the middleware that needs to be created using that property. Would this work: ?

```
router.get('/d', (req, res, next) => {
    var middlewareFunction = createDynamicMiddleware();
    middlewareFunction(req, res, next); // Will this still work as expected?
});
```

---

**Q3:** How are the `Request`/`Response` arguments passed to the next middleware when you call `next()` without any arguments?

Answer (score 0):

> **Q1**: In a middleware function, if I send() the Response, pass to the next function, or just return, does any of the remaining code get
>   executed?

```
router.get('/a', (req, res, next) => {
    res.sendStatus(200);
    // Does this ever get executed?
    //    Yes, but don't call next() or res.send() or it will throw an error

}); 

router.get('/b', (req, res, next) => {
    next();
    // Does this ever get executed?
    //    Yes, but don't call next() or res.send() or it will throw an error

}); 

router.get('/c', (req, res, next) => {
    return;
    // Does this stop the middleware chain? What happens to the request/response?
    //    The request get stuck and after a while it will fail due 'timeout'
});
```

> **Q2**: Can you pass on to another middleware function from inside of the preceding one? My reason for this is that I have to supply an
>   argument to create a certain middleware, and that argument is
>   dependent on which Express app object is the owner of the Request. So
>   I need to access a property of the Request before it is passed to the
>   middleware that needs to be created using that property.

Your factory of dynamic middleware should return a new function

Functions that returns new functions, are also knows as curried functions, here is a practical example:

```
// based on 'someId' we will return a specific middleware

req.get('/user/:someId', 
 createDynamicMiddleware,
 (req,res) => { 
  res.send('ok') 
 })

function createDynamicMiddleware(req,res,next){
  if(req.params.someId === 'me') {
    return function(req, res, next){
     // do some stuff if someId is me
     return next();
    }
  } else {
    return function(req, res, next){
     // do some other stuff otherwise
     return next();
    }
  }
}
```

> **Q3**: How are the Request/Response arguments passed to the next middleware when you call next() without any arguments?

Express handle this for you!

Also, if you add a property to req or res objects, it will be present in the next middlewares

For example:

```
router.get('/', (req,res,next) => {
  req.customProperty = 'hello!';
  return next();
}, (req, res) => {
  console.log(req.myCustomProperty)
  // hello!
})
```